# Negate unary operator in Hibernate QL

Tags: java, hibernate, operators, unary-operator

I'm trying to switch boolean field using the following hql:

```
update Entity e set e.booleanField = not e.booleanField where e.id = ?1;
```

Unfortunately "QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: not near..." was thrown.

My question is: is there some unary operator for hibernate that supports such expression? Or any well known trick?

sql supports such queries (postgresql):

```
update entity_table set booleanField = not(booleanField);
```

Comment: [Supposedly](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) HQL supports `not` in the expressions, but I'm not sure if that applies to expressions outside `where` clause. You may want to try a common hack `set e.booleanField = 1 - e.booleanField` to work around this problem.

Comment: Sorry, doesnt work. "ERROR: operator does not exist: integer - boolean"

Comment: Here is another hack way of expressing `NOT`: `set e.booleanField = (e.booleanField==false)`.

Comment: update Entity e set e.booleanField = !e.booleanField where e.id = ?1;   update Entity e set e.booleanField != e.booleanField where e.id = ?1; Did you try something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use a native SQL query for this.

Answer (score 4):

To toggle the boolean property, equivalent to the `not` unary operator, under HQL/JPQL, use:

```
UPDATE entity e SET e.booleanField = (e.booleanField=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

To toggle the boolean property in HQL, you can do this:

```
update entity_table set booleanField = ( (booleanField + 1) % 2);
```

I tested and it worked fine for me using HQL. Otherwise using (!booleanField) or (not booleanField) or (booleanField = false) didn't worked.